# Importing SQL queries in SQLite in a Batch in iPhone preogramatically

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

In my application as I release a new version, I alter my existing database tables by adding a new table or altering existing tables in SQlite.

I have written the same in script/text file and want to just import in a form of batch directly into existing database where these queries will execute once.

I know that i can do same by writing each alter query separately but this will also increase execution time and time for writing question.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I used to was to keep an array of colums for each table, like

persons = {[ fname, lname, address, zip ]}

then I also have another version array, that tells me I have for version 1, persons, 4 colums.

Then when I updated the application, and add f.ex. gsm to the persons, I update the array and the count. Then I run the query on the database sqlite_master, parse the data

you can run '.schema persons' to get the create statement. This is just work you do once, and you never run alter table on tables up to date this way. You need to be organized.